# Why does splice need an index of [0] at the end of this statement to store the value of the spliced item?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have recently discovered a solution to a splicing issue I had where I could not access the value of the spliced object from an array of objects I have, it would show it as "undefined" when I tried to print the spliced object like this -

```
function QuoteSplicing() {
    //splice quotes from the original array and push them into a new array.
        spliceQuote = quotes.splice(quoteObject, 1);
        quotes2.push(spliceQuote);
        console.log(quotes);
        console.log(quotes2);

        if(quotes.length == 0){
            quotes = quotes2;
            quotes2 = [];
        }

        return spliceQuote;
}
```

I then wrote a function that printed the spliced quote but it would show up as "undefined."

I fixed my QuoteSplicing function by adding an index value at the end of the splice statement -

```
function QuoteSplicing() {
    //splice quotes from the original array and push them into a new array.
        spliceQuote = quotes.splice(quoteObject, 1)[0];
        quotes2.push(spliceQuote);
        console.log(quotes);
        console.log(quotes2);

        if(quotes.length == 0){
            quotes = quotes2;
            quotes2 = [];
        }

        return spliceQuote;
}
```

I have the fix after looking around, but I am trying to understand the why here as I feel it is important, how does adding the [0] index to the end cause the spliced quote to not show up as undefined anymore?

Comment: splice returns an array of all removed elements, in your case, 1 element.

Comment: So by using [0] I am getting the value of the first index of the returned array of all removed (1) elements?

Comment: Yes. compare these results: `var test = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]; var spliced = test.splice(2); console.log(spliced); console.log(spliced[0]);`. The first console.log gives you an entire array, while the second console.log gives you the first element inside that array (which has only one).

Comment: Looking at a value's type and class can be helpful.

var test = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]; var spliced = test.splice(2); 
console.log(typeof spliced); 
console.log(spliced.constructor);
console.log(spliced); 

console.log(typeof spliced[0]);
console.log(spliced[0].constructor);
console.log(spliced[0]);